# Can´t run VMs on VMware Fusion - MacOS High Sierra - Cannot find a valid peer process to connect to

Tags: macos, high-sierra, virtualization, vmware

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

VMware Fusion 10.1.3

Error message:
"Cannot find a valid peer process to connect to."

Already clicked Allow on Privacy and Security for VMware Inc. but the button doesn´t work.

How else might I troubleshoot this?

Comment: It could be that the VMware Fusion kernel extension is being blocked. Open System Preferences>Security and Privacy and check whether this message is shown: "System software from developer "VMWare, Inc." was blocked from loading". If that's the case, you need to click the button "Allow" next to it (credit:  https://superuser.com/questions/1256489/how-to-fix-vmware-fusion-pro-10-cannot-find-a-valid-peer-process-to-connect-to)

Comment: Hi! The problem is that the Allow button does nothing. Doesn't work. Any other hints? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's cleary described in your question but I kind of missed it. I'd expect the Allow button to work, so I guess that some component couldn't install properly. Instead of troubleshooting just take the easy road and reinstall VMware Fusion (important: uninstall with the uninstaller provided with the Fusion image).

Answer (score 1):

I found the allow button wouldn't work as I was running magicprefs mouse software. I disabled this and the button then worked. However that didn't fix the problem for very long and the VM continues to crash.